# Can't See Progress Towards "Convention" Badge

Tags: feature-request, bug

I don't think I currently have the qualities needed to put myself forward as a candidate for Moderator at this time, but in this current Mod election I wondered what qualifications there were to be considered -- I might want to become a Mod some day, after all.

I noticed the Badge prerequisites, but was perplexed about the "Convention" badge.  It isn't listed in the lists of badges, although it does have a page: [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention).

I tried to see if I could set it as my next badge in the badge progress widget, but it isn't selectable (it doesn't even show up as *available*!).

Is this by intention, or oversight that this badge doesn't show up in the list of badges, and can't be selected in the progress widget?  If by intention, I'd like to know why, and if by oversight, could it be added?

**ETA**:

In response to @animuson, while it can be found on Main, the badge does not show up in the list on Meta.  Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Meta runs off a separate database than the main Stack Overflow site. It's likely not feasible to jack into a second database to get up-to-date results for tracking that badge. That's why your reputation only gets updated from main to here every so often instead of instantly.

Comment: @animuson, while in Meta I can see the badges I have received in Meta.  While in Main I can see the badges I have received in Main.  My main question is, why doesn't this badge show up in the *lists* of available badges, and by extension the badge progress widget.  Seems unreasonable.

Comment: It does show up in the list [on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). It's under the Participation badges.

Comment: Yes, @animuson, it shows on SO Main, but not SO Meta.  See my edit.

Comment: Right, because you can't earn a badge for participating on the Meta site *on* the Meta site. The badge would be self-referential here.

Comment: So why the downvotes?  Trying to kill my progress towards *Convention*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[You cannot track badges, like Convention, in the new profile.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253518/154928) This is [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

> Not all badges can be tracked. We had to drop a few where tracking
>   would cause unacceptable performance issues.

---

While reputation is shared between the Main and Meta sites, badges are not. The Convention badge is unique to the Main site and does not exist on Meta, so you will not find it there. I know this is confusing, since the Convention badge deals with the amount of upvoted posts you have on Meta.

[image]

---

Comment: It looks like the meta and chat badges are both excluded from the progress trackers.

Comment: I wonder if they did that intentionally because of issues they would have caused with Meta sites (seeing as they have no chat rooms either).

Comment: Both chat and meta use separate databases from the main site. Connecting to multiple databases just for the sake of tracking a badge's progress probably wasn't worth it. I'm guessing, but that's the most logical reason.

Comment: I have the badge but can verify it doesn't show up when looking for badges to track and clicking the "All" tab instead of "Available"

Comment: I just checked, and Convention does NOT show up in the Select your next badge widget in SO Main.  I hesitate to upload the screenshot to prove it, since my question is already long enough with the current image.

Comment: Nowadays it doesn't even show up in main