# Why isn't the Pundit Badge displayed on the Next Badge list?

Tags: discussion, design, badges

Users' [have asked for some time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284517/progress-bar-for-badges) a way to control the Pundit Badge. There's even a post on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports) with links for queries on the SEDE to keep track of the various badges, such [as this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228759/progress-towards-commentator-pundit) for the Pundit Badge.

With the new design and the adition of "Next Badge" it would be nice to be able to keep track of the Pundit Badge.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290433/908174) states the Pundit Badge is available on the Next Badge list, but I'm not able to see it:

[image: Unable to see the Pundit Badge on the Next Badge list]

Is it me or there's no Pundit Badge on the Next Badge list?

Comment: Some badges, like Pundit, are not on the next badge list. Similar question here: [Can't See Progress Towards “Convention” Badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290885/cant-see-progress-towards-convention-badge)

Comment: @mmking Thanks for that, I haven't found it. It's a shame though : \